# Arduino cannot communicate with PC after running servo

Tags: servo

I was messing around with my arduino uno r3 and servo today. The book I got said to run the servo through the arduino. Everything was fine. I started changing the code, and then things started to get bad. I noticed that if I did not put a delay in between the servo movements, the board would freeze, and I would have to get lucky. Well now I just can't communicate with the board. I plug the board in to my pc, windows 7 makes the connection sound, the board turns on the ON light, the L light flashes, then goes steady. In the arduino software, the COM3 port, which is where I'm plugging it in, is not coming up. Only COM1 is there. I'm not sure what to do. The board is still functioning, the servo moves. I tried to plug it in with a different port and with the servo disconnected but it still doesn't want to communicate with my pc. The code I'm using is below

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo1;

void setup()
{
  servo1.attach(9);
}

void loop()
{ 
  servo1.write(50);
  delay(500);
  servo1.write(90);
  delay(500);
  servo1.write(140);
  delay(1000);

  for(int i = 50;i<140;i+=10){
    servo1.write(i);
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

I would also like to add that I understand that you shouldn't run the servos through an arduino. I was following the book, and began researching when things went down hill.

Comment: Look at your serial devices or unkown devices in device manager.  It only takes a pullup resistor to get the device sound, quite a bit more has to be intact for a functioning port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had some problems in the past reprogramming my Arduino Uno if it writes to the serial port - I don't know if the problem is the same, but here's how I got around it:

Option 1: Hold down the reset switch, then plug your Arduino into the USB port. Select the right COM port (if needed), compile your code (something ultra simple, e.g. blink led), and then, JUST BEFORE IT STARTS UPLOADING, release the reset switch. Wash, rinse, repeat, until you get it to work, through blind luck.

Option 2: Get hold of a ICSP (such as the one I got, USBASP made by FreeTronics  http://www.freetronics.com.au/products/usbasp-icsp-programmer-for-avr-arduino#.VL8Vv3WjlIc which I am v. happy with), plug it into the serial port, plug the other end onto your Arduino UNO ICSP header (6 pins, opposite end of the board from USB), then select Tools -> Burn Bootloader. Overwrites any program, works 100% of the time. Now you can unplug your USBASP, and plug your Uno back in and program it normally. This is also a great tool if you end up using AtMega (or AtTiny) chips directly (AtMega is the chip used to do all the work on the Arduino).

To avoid this, I have gotten into the habit of putting a 5 second delay as the first thing in the startup code.

FOR FUTURE GENERATIONS: I got mine here in New Zealand, so that will probably not help most people. FreeTronics makes them, and I am very happy I got their one (they have a "slow clock" jumper that is very convenient when programming Atmel chips not on an Arduino board), I expect that any USBASP would do the trick too - in response to the question, Amazon has a couple under $4, and I expect that the price will not go up.

Search for "USBASP". Make sure you get a ribbon cable. For Arduino Uno, you need a 6-pin ribbon cable. It is also possible to use these cables to communicated directly with a running Arduino over these same pins.

Comment: I would do option 1 however I cannot select COM3/4, which is where I plug my arduino in. Can you point me in the direction of an USBASP. Preferably an Amazon Prime item so that I can get the product quickly.

Comment: It just started communicating with the pc again... strange but thankful. Quickly added what you suggested (the 5 second delay) to the start. Thanks for the help.